# Multiple variable assignment with Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

How can I initialize multiple variables at once?

```
var alpha, beta, theta = null
console.log alpha #=> null 
console.log beta  #=> null
console.log theta #=> null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be something like

alpha = beta = theta = null